# SQL query for deletion

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Consider following table

```
id  || C1  || C2  || C3 || Timestamp
--------------------------------
1   || a   || b   || 1  || t1
2   || a   || b   || 1  || t2
3   || a   || b   || 2  || t3
4   || a   || b   || 2  || t4
5   || a   || b   || 2  || t5
6   || b   || d   || 3  || t6
7   || b   || d   || 3  || t7
```

C3 contains a distinct value for a given combination of C1 and C2. A given combination of C1, C2 and C3 can have multiple rows with differing timestamps(like rows 4,5).

However, duplication has lead to creation of more than one C3 for a given C1 and C2 pair. So here rows 3, 4 and 5 violated the rule as a new C3(2) was introduced. C3 is always unique given C1 and C2.

I want to keep the latest( w.r.t timestamp) combination of C1, C2, C3 and delete all the older ones. So only rows 3,4,5 should exist and 1,2 should be removed.
**By latest I mean that older C3 values for given C1,C2 should be removed, so in this case rows 1,2 are removed but 3,4,5 remain.**

[image]

For example, given unique nid and original columns, all the rows with mock_id YR should be removed.

I have tried various queries and joins, but unable to figure out something that would solve this exact problem.

Comment: This question is asked and answered (often correctly) several times a day. Note that for large datasets, it can be quicker to construct a new table, retaining just the desired data, and then replace the old table with that.

Comment: In addition, the expected output you gave does not agree with the sentence which precedes it.

Comment: I have edited the question to provide more clarity. Consider C3 as a unique hash value, C1, C2 should only have only one, but somehow I have now got another C3. So I need to remove rows containing the older C3 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the solution I have come up with in regards to my problem, and it works fine on a test data set. Gordons answer was near, but resulted in the same logic as provided by Tim. I changed that a bit to just fetch the most up to date C3 values and then delete the ones that are not present on this set.

I had to use "from" twice due to a mysql error that prevents updates on target table through from clause. Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause) that explains the problem better.

```
delete from strings where strings.C3 not in 
( select C3 from 
    ( select C3 from strings join 
        ( select C1, C2, max(timestamp) as max_timestamp from strings group by C1, C2 ) t2
        on strings.C1 = t2.C1
        and strings.C2 = t2.C2
        and strings.Timestamp = max_timestamp 
    ) as t3
);
```

Comment: This works provided the same C3 cannot occur for different C1/C2 pairs. I find my answer more readable, but you are right, that MySQL has a problem with using the same table in an update or delete, which is usually circumvented with replacing `from mytable` by `from (select * from mytable)`. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: And I still think that the main problem you are facing is the flawed data model that made the inconsistencies even possible.

Comment: The value of C3 is always distinct. So for any given C1/C2 pair, it will always be unique. I have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: Well, I inherited this DB and need to get this solved asap. But thanks for the suggestion, will keep in mind when moving this to a new schema

Comment: I know that C3 is considered unique for a C1/C2 pair (which is essentially the problem, as you must now delete inconsistent additional C3s). But what about *other* C1/C2? Can they have the same C3? If so, your delete statement is not sufficient.

Comment: The value of C3 here is always unique across the table. I agree, if that was not the case then this would not work.

Answer (score 3):

We can try using exists logic here:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.C1 = t1.C1 AND t2.C2 = t1.C2 AND t2.C3 > t1.C3);
```

In plain English, this query says to delete any record for which we can find another having the same `C1` and `C2` values, but a *greater* `C3` value.  If such another record exists, then it means that the current record being examined is not the latest and should be deleted.

Comment: Hi Tim. I believe this solution would result in only distinct combinations of C1,C2,C3 with latest timestamps. I am looking to remove the extra C3 combinations only.

Comment: @arjunkhera I have made a slight edit to my answer per your updated logic.

Comment: I would have done this provided the values were always increasing in order, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

> C3 contains a distinct value for a given combination of C1 and C2.

Then there should be two tables. One that assigns a C3 to each C1/C2 pair and one that contains *either* C1+C2 *or* C3, plus the timstamp.

Anyway, you want to delete all rows for which a newer timestamp for the same C1/C2 pair with a different C3 exists:

```
delete from mytable
where exists
(
  select null
  from (select * from mytable) newer
  where newer.c1 = mytable.c1
    and newer.c2 = mytable.c2
    and newer.c3 <> mytable.c3
    and newer.timestamp > mytable.timestamp
);
```

Writing `from (select * from mytable) newer` instead of a mere `from mytable newer` is necessary in MySQL, because of a weird restriction that you cannot use the same table directly in an update or delete.

Comment: The timestamp appears to not be relevant, q.v. the comments under my answer.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: Your answer before the last edit that arjunkhera's comment refers to looked almost like mine, but you had `t2.C3 = t1.C3`. Thus you didn't delete old different C3s as requested, but kept all latest rows per C1/C2/C3 instead. I do think the timestamp is important and we shouldn't rely on a new C3 being greater than a previous one. I am convinced my query is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, use `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select c1, c2, c3, max(timestamp) as max_timestamp
          from t
          group by c1, c2, c3
         ) tt
         on tt.c1 = t.c1 and
            tt.c2 = t.c2 and
            tt.c3 = t.c3 and
            tt.max_timestamp > t.timestamp;
```